# Google Calendar API android create event

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I`m trying create a event with file a (.pdf) in android App with Google Calendar API: [Create Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events)

```
public static void addAttachment(Calendar calendarService, Drive driveService, String calendarId,
    String eventId, String fileId) throws IOException {
  File file = driveService, android .files().get(fileId).execute();
  Event event = calendarService.events().get(calendarId, eventId).execute();

  List<EventAttachment> attachments = event.getAttachments();
  if (attachments == null) {
    attachments = new ArrayList<EventAttachment>();
  }
  attachments.add(new EventAttachment()
      .setFileUrl(file.getAlternateLink())
      .setMimeType(file.getMimeType())
      .setTitle(file.getTitle()));

  Event changes = new Event()
      .setAttachments(attachments);
  calendarService.events().patch(calendarId, eventId, changes)
      .setSupportsAttachments(true)
      .execute();
}
```

I copy totaly this but it doesnt work,Android Studio put in red getAlternateLink() and getTitle()doesnt reconize, specifically the lines:

```
attachments.add(new EventAttachment()
      .setFileUrl(file.getAlternateLink())
      .setMimeType(file.getMimeType())
      .setTitle(file.getTitle()));
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any exceptions?

Comment: Android Studio put in red getAlternateLink() and getTitle()

Comment: From the documentation in where you copy your code, it is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events) that "You must perform a full sync of all events before enabling the `supportsAttachments` parameter for event modifications when adding attachments support into your existing app that stores events locally. If you do not perform a sync first, you may inadvertently remove existing attachments from user's events." Also, note that the code you are doing demonstrates how to update an existing event to add an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drive API V3 , You need to get metadata of drive file . First get the Drive file and then Meta data . Metadata object have all 3 values .

```
Task<Metadata> metadataTask = getDriveResourceClient().getMetadata(driveFile.getDriveId().asDriveResource());

Tasks.await(metadataTask);
Metadata meta =  metadataTask.getResult();

Event event = mService.events().get(calendarId, eventId).execute();
List<EventAttachment> attachments = event.getAttachments();
if (attachments == null) {
    attachments = new ArrayList<>();
}

Event changes = new Event();
attachments.add(new EventAttachment()
        .setFileUrl(meta.getAlternateLink())
        .setMimeType(meta.getMimeType())
        .setTitle(meta.getTitle()));
changes.setAttachments(attachments);

mService.events()
        .patch(calendarId, eventId, changes)
        .setSupportsAttachments(true)
        .execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drive:v3 doesnt exit getALternateLink() change de version to v2 in app

```
//    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev64-1.22.0') {
//        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
//    }
```

put this

```
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```